# Handlebars re-rendering template with updated data

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

```
{{#each dogs}}
<li>{{this.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Imagine I use ajax to update my list above how do I recompile the template after it's done? I can do location.reload() but that's not good for the UX. Since I'm using handlebars I shouldn't use jquery to generate my html and update the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You can recompile the template using the `Handebars.compile(data)` method as many times as you like.
Who's says you can't use jQuery to generate and update the DOM when using Handlebars?

But, you don't need to recompile (thanx @dandavis!), in order to update the data. Here is a little demo, that compiles Handlebars template once, and then just updates the template data and appends it on the DOM using jQuery, after each new Ajax call: [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/learnjavascript/mh7b4b2e/)

Comment: Yep. That's right. I've updated the answer. Thanks @dandavis.